# Unable to get user profile images from AppWeb

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

When fetching user profile data using CSOM, we are able to get the PictureURL property. However, when we attempt to display it, we're given the generic 'Image Not Found' image.

Initial (brief) investigation led me to this article: http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-enabling-cross-domain-profile-pictures​

Which seems to suggest that we're attempting to download the image from across a different domain, and SharePoint 2013 does not allow this by default.

The article provides a fix, but this seems to only apply to the on-premise version of SP2013. Office 365 version does not have that cmdlet installed/enabled.

What is the O365 way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the cross-domain library.

Here is the article on MSDN : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179927.aspx

Look at the next steps on the bottom of the article for more samples.

This one seems to solve your issue : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161183.aspx

Comment: That looks like it's using a Sandbox Solution (deprecated).. isn't it?

Comment: Also note we get the URL of the profile image, it's just the image won't display in an iframe.  I can't see how I can get an IMG tag to use the cross-domain library...?

Comment: No this is for an App for SharePoint 2013, which isn't deprecated. Have you tried it?